# Indexing certain elements within a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP array created by the mysqli_fetch_array() function. The array holds several rows, and without looping through them, can I grab each row one by one?

I have tried:

```
$links= mysqli_fetch_array($links_result); 

echo $links['link'][0];
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. What could I be doing wrong? Is this possible?

Comment: use foreach() function

Comment: try `print_r($links)` and check whats inside.

Comment: try with print_r($links) and what you get output mention here so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
$links= mysqli_fetch_array($links_result);
```

you get the next row in result set in `$links` just access them by the column names.

you can loop over the results like

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($links_result)) {

    while($links= mysqli_fetch_array($links_result)) {

       //each row in here 
       var_dump($links);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field name is 'link'

Without looping:
   echo $links[0]['link'];

where '0' is your row number

so, for row #505 it will be:
  echo $links[505]['link'];

Just make sure it exists ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without loop you can grab each row of array using recursive function
like this:

```
function printarray_withoutloop($userarray,$elementindex)
{
    if(count($userarray) > $elementindex + 1)
    {
        echo $userarray[$elementindex]['link'];
        printarray_withoutloop($userarray,$elementindex + 1)
    }
    elseif(count($userarray) == $elementindex + 1)
    {
        echo $userarray[$elementindex]['link'];
    }
}

$links= mysqli_fetch_array($links_result); 
$elementindex=0;
printarray_withoutloop($links,$elementindex);
```